# cURL PHP for tika or there is a better alternative?

Tags: php, curl, apache-tika

I am building an application where frequently I have to make GET and POST requests to a Tika server. This would be to (in response to user demand) fetch the XML/HTML of a remote PDF and further process it, or getting the media type of a remote file, etc.

Do I have to use cURL PHP scripts in my HTML to hit the server or there is another better way to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "hit" a Tika server? What are you actually trying to accomplish? Please add in more detail into the question.

Comment: @halfer: send PUT and GET requests to the server.

Comment: Well, yes, but for what purpose?

Comment: @halfer: E.g., fetching (on user demand) the XML/HTML of a remote .pdf and further process it, or getting the media type of a remote file etc.

Comment: I would say cURL is an ideal way to do this. For simple fetches you can do `file_get_contents` over HTTP, but there's nothing wrong with cURL.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [PhpTikaWrapper](https://github.com/pierroweb/PhpTikaWrapper)
Seems if fulfills your requirements